# Best practice to deliver Core Data App with content?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios4

Hey guys,
what would you say is the best way to **ship initial data** with an Core Data iOS App?

Is it maybe to once run the app, store the data and then insert the datafile in the build?
There must be a better way..

Answer (score 4):

I have had good experiences with loading the data into a sqlite backing in the simulator, and then bundling the resulting sqlite file with the app.

Especially for bigger datasets, first-run filling of the database is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

I've been toying around with the same problem myself, recently; and what I opted for was to store the data in the app in some easily parsable (for me) format, and parse and incorporate it on first run.